# input box remains visible behind jquertyui dialog

Tags: html, jquery-ui-dialog

I used [jqueryui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) . There are input boxes in the page. When the dialog appears on clicking a link, then the input boxes  are visible from behind the dialog body resulting into bad visibility of the dialog body text etc.

$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" /><input type="text" value="3" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" /><input type="text" value="3" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" /><input type="text" value="3" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" /><input type="text" value="3" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" /><input type="text" value="3" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" /><input type="text" value="3" class="input_box" />
<input type="text" value="" class="input_box" />

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
```

How to refrain the input boxes from distorting the modal window body part?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `modal:true` the background will be grayed out.

```
$(function() { $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal:true}); });
```

If you want the entire background to be hidden you can change the overlay to a solid color using CSS:

```
.ui-widget-overlay{
    background: gray;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WBstB/1/

Comment: still the prob exists

Comment: So you don't want anything in the background?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed See the updated solution and fiddle. Is that more like it?

Comment: that makes the whole page content behind the dialog hidden.

Comment: is it possible to use opacity only for the dialog body part, not for the full page ?

Comment: adding a `background-color` for dialog `div` solved the problem